# Replacing spaces in a string with "-". Whilst using fmt.Scan for user input. (Golang)

Tags: go

*(Disclaimer: my first post on Stack Overflow and also very new to Go and coding in general. I apologise if this questions lacks specific requirements. So, please tell me what I could change, if needed).*

Firstly, a description of what I'm trying to achieve:

I am trying to create a URL generator for footpatrol.com. The programme will require some user input like, the product name and the number part of the product code (SKU). Then it will return a URL which directly goes to the entered product.

The problems I'm having are with the 'productName' variable (code will be provided below). The product name will need to be returned like 'colour-brand-model-etc-etc'. However, my programme doesn't do this yet. I have tried using the function Replace(), but I'm not getting the desired results. In fact, I'm not getting any results and it just returns the first word I input.

My question is, how do I replace spaces in the string with '-'. 
Specific code I've tried:

`newstr := strings.Replace(str, " ", "-", -1)`. The code below will hopefully make more sense. 
Furthermore, it only returns the first word I input. For example, if I input 'White Nike Air Force 1', it'll return 'White'. See the code below and I'd appreciate any help I can get.

**The code which is not working and the working code below this one:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

)

var skuNumber int
var productName []string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(`PLEASE NOTE: A Footpatrol product URL requires the "colour" followed by the name of product. Each word is seperated by a hyphen.`)

    fmt.Print("Enter the product name: ")
    str, err := fmt.Scanln(&productName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    newstr := strings.Replace(string(str), " ", "-", -1)
    fmt.Scanln(&newstr)

    fmt.Print("Enter the SKU number: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&skuNumber)

    fmt.Print("https://www.footpatrol.com/product/", newstr, "/", skuNumber, "_footpatrolcom/\n")

}
```

**Code which works but requires exact URL input**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var skuNumber int
var productName string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(`PLEASE NOTE: A Footpatrol product URL requires the "colour" followed by the name of product. Each word is seperated by a hyphen.`)

    fmt.Print("Enter the product name: ")
    fmt.Scan(&productName)

    fmt.Print("Enter the SKU number: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&skuNumber)

    fmt.Print("https://www.footpatrol.com/product/", productName, "/", skuNumber, "_footpatrolcom/\n")

}

Output: 
go run .\main.go
PLEASE NOTE: A Footpatrol product URL requires the "colour" followed by the name of product. Each word is seperated by a hyphen.
Enter the product name: red-nike-zoom-spiridon-cage-2
Enter the SKU number: 341503
https://www.footpatrol.com/product/red-nike-zoom-spiridon-cage-2/341503_footpatrolcom/
```

Comment: Your fmt.Scanln usage is wrong. Use `productName string` not `[]string`, and the output of `Scanln` is in `productName`, not `str`.

Answer (score 0):

1., You should use `strings.ReplaceAll` instead of `strings.Replace`.
2., In your working example just add the following line after `fmt.Scan()`.

```
...
fmt.Scan(&productName)
productName = strings.ReplaceAll(productName, " ", "-")
...
```

This will replace all the occurrences of space after you read the productName.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response! I tried what you said but it didn't do anything unfortunately. I added ```productName = strings.ReplaceAll(productName, " ", "-")``` after my ```fmt.Scan()``` line. But it still doesn't change anything. In fact the output looks this: If I enter 'Nike Air Force 1' in the product name field, it finishes the programme with 'Nike' as the productName variable and '0' for the skuNumber variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, of course. I forget about the fmt.Scan, it's always read until the first space.
You should use bufio instead.    
`
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)    
fmt.Print("Enter the product name: ")    
productName, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')     
productName = strings.ReplaceAll(productName, "\n", "")     
productName = strings.ReplaceAll(productName, " ", "-")    
`